# The java.time.LocalDate parameter processes as java.util.Date in hibernate query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to pass a `java.time.LocalDate` parameter to a named query but Hibernate wrongly expected parameter of `java.util.Date` type.
 I'm using Java 8 on Spring Boot 2.2.5 (with Hibernate 5.4.12 and JPA 2.2.5).

Exception:

```
    Exception - org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [2020-03-30] did not match expected type [java.util.Date (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [2020-03-30] did not match expected type [java.util.Date (n/a)]
```

DAO method:

```java
java.time.LocalDate date = LocalDate.now(); // example date
result = entityManager.createNamedQuery("MyTableEntity.query", MyTableEntity.class)
        .setParameter("date", date)
        .setMaxResults(1)
        .getSingleResult();
```

Named query:

```java
@NamedQuery(name = "MyTableEntity.query", query = "SELECT o FROM MyTableEntity o WHERE date(o.timestamp) = :date")
```

Entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_table")
public class MyTableEntity implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "time_control")
    private java.time.OffsetDateTime timestamp;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // constructors...
    // getters and setters...
}
```

I think the problem (bug?) is in the named query where the cast from `Timestamp` to `Date` generate a `java.util.Data` type.
In fact if I query another entity with a `LocalDate` type parameter on an attribute of the same type it works as expected.

However I resolved this by passing `java.sql.Date.valueOf(date)` as parameter, but I want to know why Hibernate did not resolve `LocalDate` as I expected.

Comment: What hibernate dialect do you use?

Comment: https://thoughts-on-java.org/persist-localdate-localdatetime-jpa/

Comment: @SternK I'm using MySQL8 dialect.

Comment: @xex593 I'm using JPA 2.2 that support `java.time.LocalDate` as standard type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each function that you use in hql/jpql query should be declared in the hibernate dialect that you use. It looks like in your case the declaration of the `date` function looks somehow like this:

```java
import org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes;

public YourDialect {

  // ...
  registerFunction( "date", new StandardSQLFunction( "date", StandardBasicTypes.DATE ) );

}
```

and below you can see how the `StandardBasicTypes.DATE` is defined:

```java
/**
 * The standard Hibernate type for mapping {@link java.util.Date} ({@link java.sql.Date}) to JDBC
 * {@link java.sql.Types#DATE DATE}.
 *
 * @see TimeType
 */
public static final DateType DATE = DateType.INSTANCE;
```

That is why you got the mentioned in your question exception. You can change this by redefining the `date` function in the following way:

```java
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardSQLFunction;
import org.hibernate.type.LocalDateType;

public class MyDialect extends SomeHibernateDialect
{
   public MyDialect()
   {
      super();
      registerFunction( "date", new StandardSQLFunction( "date", LocalDateType.INSTANCE ) );
   }
}
```

And then use this dialect. After that you initial query will work.

Comment: Exactly as you said; the _date_ function is defined by `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect` that I'm currently using.
I thought that was an Hibernate bug since I know that from JPA 2.2 the `java.time.LocalDate` is supported as standard and so I thought that it would resolved without any problem by auto converting to the mapped type at runtime.

Wich is for you, in this case, the best way to maintain the db's indipendence provided by Hibernate layer?
Thank you.

Comment: I don't think that this is a bug. I see from JPA 2.2 spec that `java.sql.Date` and `java.util.Date` are supported as well (see `2.2 Persistent Fields and Properties` section). And in your case the root cause of exception is the definition of db specific function not the entity's field mapping.

Comment: I am not sure that understand your last question. As for me, if you have one place where you should convert `LocalDate` to `java.util.Date` it's ok. But if you should do it quite frequently it would be good to localize this in one place.

Comment: Ok, I understood that the "problem" was in the returned type of that function defined by MySQL specs.
So for every not stantard SQL funcion I use, I need to exactly know which is the expeted return type to correctly map it to a Java object. But in this way I am conditioned from the db specifications I'm currently using; so my question was: wich is for you the best practice to mantain indipendence from db implementation (MySQL, Oracle, etc)? Thank you.

Comment: The hibernate dialect is the layer that allow to encapsulate all database specific features. If you are going to use some function from one dialect and you should have an ability to switch to another dialect then you should have an analog with the same signature in this new dialect.

Comment: You should also take in mind that this flexibility to prevent you from usage all riches of facilities of particular database.